# Compare the textbox value with the data in database and update the changes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing a stock buy and sell program. Currently I am working on the stock buying page. I am showing the data in gridview which is databounded, and a textbox to let users to key in the amount of stock that they wanted to buy and click the buy button. when the button is clicked, how do I compare the value of textbox with the value in the database?

If the stock unit in the database is smaller than the amount of being entered in the textbox, an alert will pop up and will not continue, and if the value is bigger than the amount entered in the textbox, it will update the value in the database.

The textbox is `amount` and the column for comparing in the database is `stockUnit` from the table `stockDetails`.

i have used this code below to retrieve data from the database, but how can i compare the data in textbox with the data in database? thx

updated the code...i tried this code and how can i udpate the data of unitavailable in database with the "unitavailable1?

```
 hookUp = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost\\SqlExpress;Database=Stocks3_Data;" +
    "Integrated Security=True");
    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  UnitAvailable  FROM StockDetails WHERE StockID = 3", hookUp);
    hookUp.Open();
    reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
    int amountkey;
    amountkey = Convert.ToInt32(amount.Text);
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        int unitavailable = reader.GetInt32(0);
        if (amountkey <= unitavailable)
        {
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> alert('The units available is not enough.')</script>");
        }
        else 
        {
            Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> alert('The units available is not enough.')</script>");
            unitavailable1 = unitavailable - amountkey;

        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    hookUp.Close();
}
```

Comment: can you show your gridview's source ?

Comment: where is your textbox? is it outside of gridview?

Comment: ya..is outside the grid view... actually the comparing don have any relationship to do wif the grid view. i used data bound for the grid view and use sqlconnection for retrieving data from the database for comparing the data in database with the value in textbox.

Comment: so with witch row of gridview you want to compare textbox if there is no relationship!

Comment: ah...i guess i make u misunderstand what i mean...sorry about that... the grid view is just to show the data in the table of database only... and i have a textbox thr for user to key in the amount to compare the data in the database, and the code above i used is to get the data from the database already. Just how should i compare the value in the textbox with the data from datatbase and update the new value into the database?

Comment: so first of all there is no role of gridview in this question.right? and what i understand is that you have a table `stockDetails` and in which three column 1 StockId 2 stockName 3 stockUnit.
Now with what data you want to compare your textbox. with sum of all stockUnit in the table or particular aby one stockID's StockUnit??

Comment: just edited the code, should be the unitavailable that i wanted to compare with the textbox. there is a 4th column which is unitavailable. and data in unitavailable is int which i wanted to compare with the value in the textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your update

Change your code like this

```
 while (reader.Read())
        {
            int unitavailable = reader.GetInt32(0);
            if (amountkey <= unitavailable)
            {
                Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> alert('The units available is not enough.')</script>");
            }
            else 
            {

                unitavailable1 = unitavailable - amountkey;
                   SqlCommand   sqlupdateCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE StockDetails  set UnitAvailable='"+unitavailable1+"' WHERE StockID = 3", hookUp);
                   sqlupdateCmd .ExecuteNonQuery(); //Update your db values
 Response.Write("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> alert('The units available is not enough.')</script>");
    }
}
```

Comment: any other query leave a comment here

Comment: i tried the code...something wrong with the whole piece of code i guess.. when i press the button which generate the code, nothing happen, the alert message did not pop up and data did not update to database

Comment: i dont know what are you doing but it is the correct approach and it is working code.just work around your code some where you are missing something.